# how to fetch data using JSON in C# webservice from iPhone app?

Tags: c#, .net, ios4, .net-4.0, json.net

I am using JSON in my web service on C# but I don't know JSON at all.

I need to fetch data in web service those are coming from iphone app and after manipulating the data, I need to return those data to app in JSON format again.

If I am doing this for login, how can I implement that?

I am simply trying to fetch the data and resend the data using json format, so is there any sample code that simply show those things?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a REST enabled WCF service. Here's a [blog post](http://debugmode.net/2011/05/15/wcf-rest-service-with-josn-data/) which illustrates with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the links

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

Also see jQuery tutorial for JSON

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/